# how to convert a tree table into json tree?

Tags: java, sql, json, algorithm, tree

Database is Oracle, the table has 3 columns: id, parent_id , name, which contains data of the company's structure.

```
id      parent_id     name
0       -1            CEO
1        0            CMO-marketing
2        0            COO - china
3        0            Mobile BU
4        0            COO - Intel
5        0            WW - Sales
6        1            Research & Tech
7        1            Communications
8        1            Human Resources
9        2            PC BU
10       2            Sales
...
```

SQL query:

```
select * from org connect by prior id = parent_id start with id = '0';
```

this SQL query can get all data.

I want to transform the output to a json tree.

```
{"children":
    [{        
        "id":0,
        "leaf":false,
        "text":"CEO",
        "children":[
            {
                "text":"CMO-marketing",
                "id":1,
                "leaf":false,
                "children":[
                    {
                        "text":"Research & Tech",
                        "id":6,
                        "leaf": true
                    },{
                        "text":"Communications",
                        "id":7,
                        "leaf": true
                    },{
                        "text":"Human Resources",
                        "id":8,
                        "leaf": true
                    }               
                ]
            },{
                "text":"COO - china",
                "id":2,
                "leaf":false,
                "children":[
                    {
                        "text":"PC BU",
                        "id":9,
                        "leaf": true
                    },{
                        "text":"Sales",
                        "id":10,
                        "leaf": true
                    }               
                ]
            },{
                "text":"Mobile BU",
                "id":3,
                "leaf":false
            },{
                "text":"COO - Intel",
                "id":4,
                "leaf":false
            },{
                "text":"WW - Sales",
                "id":5,
                "leaf":false
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

I use java, and want to an algorithm to convert it.

Comment: I'm currently trying to solve a similar problem with multiple joined tables.  I don't have a Java solution for you, but, there appear to be a number of non-java javascript solutions that might work in your "single" table situation.  Take a look at the D3 Nest functionality on these pages: https://gist.github.com/phoebebright/3176159 and http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/

Comment: @D.Woods Your work is wonderful, but i have no idea to shape it for me. Javascript solution is also suit for my project, the modification 's not complicate. Your .csv data is not a tree not like my table data.Could you say more?

Comment: Neither of those links are my work. I'm still messing with this problem.  If I ever come up with a decent working solution for my multiple table situation, I'll share it.